# How to combine me 2 query to get my second count side by side each

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT   DATENAME(MONTH,dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED)) AS MON, 
         SR_AREA, 
         COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM     S_SRV_REQ
WHERE   (INS_PRODUCT = 'PS') 
  AND   (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) BETWEEN '10/1/2015' AND '11/1/2015')
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED)), 
         SR_AREA
```

which produces this output:

```
--------+-----------------------------+------
MON     | SR_AREA                     | COUNT
--------+-----------------------------+------
October | Privacy Violation           |    42
October | Renewal/New RX CII/Narcotic |  6422
October | Refill Hold                 |   851
October | Status of RX                | 37937
October | Death Notification          |   130
October | NULL                        |     1
October | Renewal/New RX Action Taken | 21074
October | Clinical Question           |  6554
--------+-----------------------------+------
```

And I have this variation:

```
SELECT   DATENAME(MONTH,dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED)) AS MON, 
         SR_AREA, 
         COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM     S_SRV_REQ
WHERE   (INS_PRODUCT = 'PS') 
    AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) BETWEEN '10/1/2015' AND '11/1/2015') 
    AND (RESOLUTION_CD = 'External Referral')
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED)), 
         SR_AREA
```

which produces this output:

```
--------+-----------------------------+------
MON     | SR_AREA                     | COUNT
--------+-----------------------------+------
October | Identify Med Unavailable    |    22
October | Tracking Available          |  1451
October | Out of Rx                   |  3664
October | General Inquiry             |    19
October | Renewal/New RX Failed Alert |  5887
October | Nursing Home Assist         |    31
October | Renewal                     |     1
October | Tracking Unavailable        |   680
--------+-----------------------------+------
```

How to combine these 2 queries to get my second count side by side to the first.

Comment: Be careful when tagging. mysql <> sql server.

Comment: Your second query has external referral in a where clause. And not in the first one. Is that all there is in difference?

Comment: Could you show the table structure. Like resolution_cd etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a `CASE WHEN` construct, like this:

```
SELECT   DATENAME(MONTH,dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED)) AS MON, 
         SR_AREA, 
         COUNT(*) AS COUNT,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN RESOLUTION_CD='External Referral' THEN 1 END) AS COUNT2
FROM     S_SRV_REQ
WHERE   (INS_PRODUCT = 'PS') 
    AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) BETWEEN '10/1/2015' AND '11/1/2015') 
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH,dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED)), 
         SR_AREA
```